# How to use Highcharts theme with rCharts

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I want to create my own theme for Highcharts to use them with rCharts on Shiny app. I've tried to add link to theme scrip by adding 
                      tags$head(
                        tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "js/themes/gray.js")
                      )

to ui.r. However this doesn't work. Should I call theme directly from rCharts function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the required script in your app directory:

You can put it directly in your app directory and use `includeScript("gray.js")` or place it in the `www` folder
and use  `tags$head( tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "gray.js") )`. The scripts can be found on the
highcharts github page https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/themes/gray.js .
I have included an example https://gist.github.com/johndharrison/bc1440afad69433f5e61 . You can run it by calling:

```
runGist("bc1440afad69433f5e61")
```

[image]

Comment: @kimsu happy to help consider marking the question answered by pressing the tick